# correct use of __stdcall function

Tags: c++, winapi, calling-convention

I have a client, which connects to the server and waits an answer about connection status. If the server changes the status, it sends a message to the client.
First the client register itself over a function `RegisterConnectionStatusDelegate` , which is defined as follows:

```
MNS_SDK_API void  RegisterConnectionStatusDelegate(void (CALLBACK *cb)(int idx, int status));

The CALLBACK is defined in another class as: #define CALLBACK    __stdcall
The MNS_SDK_API  is defined in in another class as: #define MNS_SDK_API __declspec(dllimport)
```

My question is, how can I use this `RegisterConnectionStatusDelegate` function in my application correctly.

My current implementation looks like:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char const *const *argv)
{
  test *client = new test();
  client->init();
}
```

**test.h**

```
class test: public CMnsApp
{
  public:
    test();
    ~test();
    void init();
    void connectToServer(const char *, const char *, int);
    void (CALLBACK *connectionStatus)(int idx, int status);
  private:
    CMnsApp *app;
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void CALLBACK connectionStatus(int idx, int status)
{
  if (status == 0)
    std::cout << "Connection OFF\n" << std::endl;
  else if (status == 1)
    std::cout << "Connection OK\n" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Connection status UNKNOWN\n" << std::endl;
}

void test::init()
{
  app = new CMnsApp();

  connectToServer("testClient", "localhost", 1390);

  // Process Windows events. typedef struct tagMSG in WinUser.h
  MSG msg;

 while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
 {
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
}

void test::connectToServer(const char *clientName, const char* hostName, int port)
{
  RegisterConnectionStatusDelegate(connectionStatus);

  app->InitMnsClientApp(clientName, hostName, port);
}
```

If I run the above code, it goes in `while` loop after creating connection but does not call the function `connectionStatus`

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: The code snippet has two identifiers named "connectionStatus".  The callback function that you actually want to be called.  And a member variable of the test class, we can't see what you do with that one or why it has to be public.  Consider deleting it or using RegisterConnectionStatusDelegate(::connectionStatus) to make it crystal that you meant to use the function.

Comment: you need remove `void (CALLBACK *connectionStatus)(int idx, int status);` member variable from class. for what you declare it ?

Comment: Removing the member variable `void (CALLBACK *connectionStatus)(int idx, int status);` from the header class didn't bring anything. The function `connectionStatus` stilt not called.

Comment: How does InitMnsClientApp() indicate failure?  You don't check a return value so cannot know that a connection was actually made.  Well, other than the callback never being fired perhaps.

Comment: I see it on the server side that the connection is created successfully and in addition I can send from client  to server some string message, if needed